# PHP Send Email button not working

Tags: php

i have a main page that calls my php page to generate the report, then on the same main page, i have a Send Email button which calls my mail php page but its not sending the generated report to the specified email address, how can i make this Send Email button work?

what i want to happen here is that after i generated the report ill send it to email keeping the same table format...

here's my mail php:

```
<?php
//for getting the variable in the URL
$WirelessRemaining= $_GET['WirelessRemaining'];
$WirelineRemaining = $_GET['WirelineRemaining'];
$dates = $_POST['dates'];
$output= $_POST['$output'];

require 'include/DB_Open.php';

 $to = "aa.aa@xy.com";
 $subject = "Test, $dates";
 $body = "$output";


 $headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
 $headers .= 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1' . "\r\n";
 $headers .= "From: aa <aa.aa@xy@ccc.com>\r\n";

 if (mail($to, $subject, $body)) {
   echo("<p>Message successfully sent!</p>");
  } else {
   echo("<p>Message delivery failed...</p>");
  }

include 'include/DB_Close.php';  
?>
```

here's the code that calls the report generator and mail php:

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#RetrieveList").on('click',function() {
        var xid = $('#XiD').val();
        var date = $('#Date').val();
        $.post('retrieve_test.php',{xid:xid, date:date}, function(data){
        $("#results").html(data);
        });
        return false;
    });

$("#Report").on('click',function() {
    var dates = $('#Date').val();
        $.post('report_sample.php',{dates:dates}, function(data){
        $("#results").html(data);
        });
        return false;
    });

$("#Email").on('click',function() {
    var date1 = $('#Date').val();
        $.post('mail.php',{date1:date1, output:output}, function(data){
        $("#results").html(data);
        });
        return false;
    });
    });
```

Comment: Are there any errors in the servers log-file?

Comment: You forgot to add your `$headers` to your `mail()`. Rest seems okay.

Comment: all i get are these messages in my main page:
Notice: Undefined index: WirelessRemaining in C:\xampp\htdocs\xxx\mail.php on line 3
Notice: Undefined index: WirelineRemaining in C:\xampp\htdocs\xxx\mail.php on line 4
Notice: Undefined index: dates in C:\xampp\htdocs\xxx\mail.php on line 5
Notice: Undefined index: $output in C:\xampp\htdocs\xxx\mail.php on line 6
Message successfully sent!

Comment: and those lines refer to this `$WirelessRemaining= $_GET['WirelessRemaining'];
$WirelineRemaining = $_GET['WirelineRemaining'];
$dates = $_POST['dates'];
$output= $_POST['$output'];`

Answer (score 0):

```
$dates = $_POST['dates'];
$output= $_POST['$output'];
```

should be

```
$dates = $_POST['date1'];
$output= $_POST['output'];
```

Comment: what are `$WirelessRemaining= $_GET['WirelessRemaining'];
$WirelineRemaining = $_GET['WirelineRemaining'];` where did you post them?

Comment: they are a text field that is part of the page when i call report generator page...so thats where i put in the remaining tickets then it'll part of the `$body = "$output";` that will be sent thru email

Answer (score 0):

Use post method form your HTML page or AJAX page.

//Sample code example

```
$("#RetrieveList").on('click',function() {
    var xid = $('#XiD').val();
    var date = $('#Date').val();
    $.post('retrieve_test.php',{xid:xid, date:date}, function(data){
    $("#results").html(data);
    });
    return false;
});
```

In PHP page

```
$date = $_POST['date'];
```

Here is the sample code
https://www.banglacleverprogrammer.life/2019/08/sending-html-email-using-php.html